# how to get result from array?

Tags: php, arrays

I have an array as below :

```
Array
(
[VA-ecoclsqty2_0_R79_31_9_1Room1]=>2",
[VA-preco2-0_R79_31_9_1Room1]=>50.00",
[VA-amt_preco2-0_R79_31_9_1Room1]=>25.00",

[VA-busclsqty4_0_R79_31_9_1Room1]=>2",
[VA-prbus4-0_R79_31_9_1Room1]=>36.00",
[VA-amt_prbus4-0_R79_31_9_1Room1]=>18.00",

[VA-busclsqty5_1_R79_31_9_1Room2]=>1",
[VA-prbus5-1_R79_31_9_1Room2]=>17.00",
[VA-amt_prbus5-1_R79_31_9_1Room2]=>17.00",

[VA-ecoclsqty6_1_R79_31_9_1Room2]=>3",
[VA-preco6-1_R79_31_9_1Room2]=>28.00",
[VA-amt_preco6-1_R79_31_9_1Room2]=>14.00",
)
```

I want to insert above data as below rule...

insert data 8 (values as 2+2+1+3) rows where

2 row insert on VA-ecoclsqty.... - amount = 25.00, roomcode = R79_31_9_1, unique_id = 1 for Room1

2 row insert on VA-busclsqty.... - amount = 18.00, roomcode = R79_31_9_1, unique_id = 2 for Room1

1 row insert on VA-busclsqty.... - amount = 17.00, roomcode = R79_31_9_1, unique_id = 3 for Room2

3 row insert on VA-ecoclsqty.... - amount = 14.00, roomcode = R79_31_9_1, unique_id = 4 for Room2

and more for different rooms for multiple rows.

How can i insert it?

And please remember that every key is different from each other.

Please reply soon and try to help.

Comment: You need to do some research and make this an actual question, there are plenty of resources online already on how to do this.

Answer (score 0):

To use ajax for the form I'd look at [jQuery ajax](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/%20'jQuery%20axaj()') function. To process the form and perform a search in you DB you'll have to setup a URL for the form to post to that does the processing and returns the correct response.